# Error when attempting to use a type from GNU's GMP library as the yylval type for Bison

Tags: c, bison, gmp

I'm attempting to use the type `mpz_t` from the GMP library as the type for `yylval` by including the following in the Bison file:

```
%define api.value.type {mpz_t}
```

I checked the generated parser and it correctly generates the line `typedef mpz_t YYSTYPE`, with `YYSTYPE` later being used to create `yylval`.

`mpz_t` is typdefed as `typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];` in the GMP header file `gmp.h`. In turn, `__mpz_struct` is typdefed as

```
typedef struct
{
    // struct members here - don't believe they're important
} __mpz_struct;
```

Bison runs without error, but whenever I try to create an executable I get the following error:

> calc.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
>
> calc.tab.c:1148:12: error:
>   incompatible types when assigning to type ‘YYSTYPE’ from type
>   ‘struct __mpz_struct *’
>
> *++yyvsp = yylval;

`yyvsp` is defined as a pointer to `YYSTYPE`.

Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Aside: `mpz_t` and friends are each typedefed as an array-of-1-struct so that function arguments of each such type are passed by "reference" even though C has no such mechanism. 20 years ago (in email conversation with the then-maintainer) I thought this was a neat hack; I'm no longer sure of that.

Comment: Look closely at anything of type `YYSTYPE` - where it's declared, defined, and used. Something (maybe written by you, maybe by Bison) is not doing the right thing with `yyvsp`, `yylval`, and/or some related variable.

Comment: @mlp: Because the parser stack is a stack, bison needs a temporary value to hold `$$`; `$$` is going to be placed exactly in the slot occupied by `$1`, and bison can't translate `$$ = ...` into `$1 = ...` without making things very confusing if the action uses `$1` after the assignment to `$$`. Also, bison wants to implement the default action `$$ = $1` (part of the yacc spec). It does this by effectively doing this: `tmp = stack[top - n + 1]; <action if any>; top -= (n - 1); stack[top - 1] = tmp;`. That includes two `YYSTYPE` assignments; I don't see why that's "not the right thing".

Comment: @rici: You said it yourself in your excellent answer: objects of type `mpz_t` can't be assigned-to; `YYSTYPE` is typedefed to `mpz_t`, so the two `YYSTYPE` assignments are "not the right thing". I have no idea what "the right thing" is here, which is why I've not tried to answer.

Comment: @mlp: I don't believe "the right thing" is possible in C. If you used the C++ bison skeleton with the C++ gmp API, then the appropriate assignment overrides would be used and the code should compile and execute without surprises (although it might be somewhat inefficient; I don't know if the C++ skeleton uses `std::move`). Given the fact that `mpz_t` is not an assignable type, I would say that The Right Thing℠ is probably what actually happens: produce an error and force the user to use an indirect reference to the object. But I guess that depends on what you think TRT means :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you say, `mpz_t` is typedef'ed as an alias for an array type:

```
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

As a result, assignment to a variable of type `mpz_t` is illegal:

```
mpz_t a, b;
mpz_init(b);
a = b;  /* Error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘mpz_t’ */
        /* from type ‘struct __mpz_struct *’                        */
```

Instead, it is necessary to use one of the built-in assignment functions:

```
mpz_t a, b;
mpz_inits(a, b, 0);
mpz_set(a, b);   /* a is now a copy of b */
```

The ban on direct assignment to an `mpz_t` is necessary because of the way gmp manages memory. See Note 1 below.

Bison assumes that the semantic type `YYSTYPE` can be assigned to (see note 2), which means that it cannot be an array type. That's normally not a problem, because normally `YYSTYPE` is a union type, and a union with an array member can be assigned to. So there is no problem using an array type with bison provided that you include it in a `%union` declaration.

But you MUST NOT do that with gmp, because although it will compile, it won't work. You'll end up with lots of leaked memory and you're likely to end up with obscure bugs, where gmp computes the wrong values (or fails in more obvious ways, like `free`ing memory out from under an `mpz_t`).

Using `mpz_t` objects directly as semantic values is possible, but it will not be easy. You will end up spending a lot of time thinking about which stack slots have semantic values which have been initialized; which ones have values which need to be `mpz_clear`ed, and a lot of other troubling details.

A simpler (but not simple) solution is to make the semantic value a *pointer to* an `mpz_t`. If you are just making a bignum calculator, you could bypass the semantic value altogether and maintain your own value stack. That will work out as long as every reduction action pops all its arguments from the value stack and pushes its result.

This value stack would also be a vector of `mpz_t` values, but it differs from the parser stack in several important ways, because it is entirely under your control:

1. You are under no obligation to create the temporary value which bison needs to create (see note 2). If you want to do an addition, for example, which would pop two operands off the stack and push the result back on, you could just do that:

   ```
   mpz_add(val_stack[top - 2], val_stack[top - 2], val_stack[top - 1]);
   --top;
   ```
2. You can initialize the value stack before parsing, and clear all elements when the parse is done. That makes memory management much simpler, and lets you reuse allocated limb vectors.
3. Tokens like operators and parentheses, which have no associated semantic value, do not occupy space on the value stack. That doesn't save much space, but it avoids the need to initialize and clear stack slots which never have useful data in them.

### Notes

#### 1. Why GMP discourages direct assignment

According to the gmp manual, making `mpz_t` (and other similar types) arrays of size 1 was simply to compensate for C's lack of pass-by-reference. Since the array decays to a pointer when used as a function argument, you get pass-by-reference without having to explicit mark the argument. But it must have crossed someone's mind that the use of an array type also prevents direct assignment to an `mpz_t`. Direct assignment cannot work because of the way gmp manages memory.

Gmp values necessarily include a reference to allocated storage. (Necessarily, because there is no limit to the size of a bignum, so different bignums are different sizes.) Generally speaking, there are two ways of managing objects like that:

1. Make the object immutable. Then it can be shared arbitrarily, because no modification is possible.
2. Always copy the object on assignment, making sharing impossible. Then objects can be modified without affecting any other object.

These two strategies are exemplified by the Java and C++ approaches to strings, for example. Unfortunately, both strategies depend on some infrastructure in the language:

- Immutable strings require garbage collection. Without a garbage collector, there is no way to tell when the storage for a string can be released. It would be possible to reference count the memory allocations, but the reference counts need to be incremented and decremented and unless you're prepared to make your code a swamp of reference count maintenance, you need some language support.
- Copying strings requires overriding the assignment operator. That's possible in C++, but few other languages are so flexible.

There are also performance problems with both of the above strategies.

- Immutable objects need to be copied when modified, which can turn simple linear complexity into quadratic complexity. This is a well-known problem with repetitive appends to Java or Python strings; Java's StringBuilder is intended to compensate for this issue. Immutable integers would be annoying; it is very common to accumulate sums, for example (`sum += value;`), and having to copy `sum` each time through such a loop could drastically slow down the loop.
- On the other hand, forcing copy on assignment makes it impossible to share constants, or even to rearrange vectors. That can cause a lot of extra copying, again leading to linear algorithms turning into quadratic algorithms.

Gmp chose the mutable object strategy. Bignums *must* be copied on assignment, and since C does not allow overriding the assignment operator, the easiest solution was to ban use of the assignment operator, forcing the  use of library functions.

Since there are occasions when it is useful to move bignums around without copying -- shuffling an array of bignums, for example -- gmp also provides a swap function. And, if you are very very careful and know more about gmp's internals than I do, it is probably possible to just use the `union` hack mentioned above, or to use `memcpy()`, in order to do a more complicated rearrangement of gmp objects, provided you maintain the important invariant:

**Every vector of limbs must be referenced by precisely one and only one `mpz_t` object.**

The reason that is important is that gmp will resize a bignum if necessary, using realloc. Suppose that `a` and `b` are `mpz_t`, and we use some hack to make them both the same bignum, sharing memory:

```
memcpy(a, b, sizeof(a));
```

Now, we make `b` much bigger:

```
mpz_mul(b, b, b);  /* Set b to b squared */
```

This will work fine, but internally it will do something like

```
tmp = realloc(b->_mp_d, 2 * b->_mp_size);
if (tmp) b->_mp_d = tmp;
```

in order to make `b` large enough to hold the result. That will work fine for `b`, but it could result in the limbs being pointed by `a` going into limbo, since a successful `realloc` which allocates new storage will automatically free the old storage.

The same thing would happen with any operation which increased the size of `b`; squaring it in place was just an example. `a` could end up with a dangling pointer after almost any modification which increases the size of `b`: `mpz_add(b, tmp1, tmp2);` (assuming `tmp1` and/or `tmp2` are larger than `b`.)

#### 2. Why Bison requires that semantic values be assignable

Bison creates a temporary `YYSTYPE` object for every reduction; this temporary is the actual variable represented as `$$` in the bison action. Before the reduction action is executed, the parser executes the equivalent of `$$ = $1;`. Once the action has been completed, `$1` through `$n` are popped off the stack, and `$$` is pushed onto it. In effect, this overwrites the old `$1` with `$$`, which is why a temporary must be used. (Otherwise, setting `$$` in an action would surprisingly invalidate `$1`.)