# How to take address of mpz_t passed as parameter in C code?

Tags: c, casting, gmp

I have C code that wants to do something like this:

```
#include <gmp.h>
extern void g(mpz_t in);
extern mpz_t temp;  /* initialized elsewhere */

void f(mpz_t in, int flag) {
  mpz_t *arg;
  if (flag) {
    mpz_mul_ui(temp, in, 2);
    arg = &temp;
  } else {
    /* this bit is the problem */
    arg = &in;
  }

  /* placeholder for more complex code using *arg (readonly) */
  g(*arg);
}
```

The purpose here is to avoid a lot of duplicated code represented here by `g(*arg)` – I want it to act either on the original input or on a modified version of it.

But while `arg = &temp` compiles fine, `arg = &in` does not. I understand that this is because `mpz_t` is typedef'd as an array (`typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1]`), and from [Error when attempting to use a type from GNU's GMP library as the yylval type for Bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516093) I get the additional clue "the array decays to a pointer when used as a function argument", but it isn't clear to me what the actual type of that pointer is so that I can do the right thing here. I've tried `arg = &in`, `arg = in`, `arg = &in[0]`, and, in each case, GCC just tells me "warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type".

My system GCC (7.5.0) sadly does not report what the incompatible types are but, trying again with a later version (11.2.0) does tell me `warning: assignment to '__mpz_struct (*)[1]' from incompatible pointer type '__mpz_struct **'`, which is great. But I can't guess from that if there's an invocation that will allow the assignment safely without a cast, or if a cast is required what I should be casting – should it be `arg = (mpz_t *)&in`? Is there a way to do this without casts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overall assessments of the problems are about right:

1. Because the `mpz_t` type is defined as an *array* (even though it has only one element), arguments of that type will decay to pointers (to the first – and only – element).
2. Also, because it is an array type, you cannot make direct assignments to objects of that type (so you couldn't just remove the `*` from the declaration of `arg`, for example).

What you *can* do, though, is to declare the local `arg` variable as a pointer to the **underlying type** of the array – that is the `__mpz_struct` type. So, you would have: `__mpz_struct* arg;`.

With this, you must then remove the address-of (`&`) operator from the right-hand side of the two `arg` assignments in your function: the `temp` array will (when used in such an expression) automatically 'decay' into a pointer; and the `in` argument has *already* decayed thusly.

Here's an outline:

```c
#include <gmp.h>
extern void g(mpz_t in);
extern mpz_t temp;  /* initialized elsewhere */

void f(mpz_t in, int flag) {
    __mpz_struct* arg; // Pointer to the underlying type of an "mpz_t" array
    if (flag) {
        mpz_mul_ui(temp, in, 2);
        arg = temp; // RHS decays into a __mpz_struct* pointer
    }
    else {
        /* problem solved: */
        arg = in; // RHS is already a __mpz_struct* pointer
    }

    /* placeholder for more complex code using arg (readonly) */
    g(arg); // Note that the "*" needs to be gone, here!
}
```

Note also that, in the above code, there is no cast used!

---

###### Notes on the use of the `mpz_t* arg;` (pointer-to-array) type and casts.

In terms of its *actual value*, the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element. However, a pointer to an array is **not** the same *type* as a pointer to its first element. We can use two methods to convert one to the other: a cast, or an "address of"/indirection operator (depending on the direction of the conversion).

Further, in almost all expressions, the use of an array identifier (without a suffixed `[...]`) will be converted to a pointer to its first element. Thus, in the expression, `x = temp` (using the `temp` from the original code), the RHS will decay to a pointer to `temp[0]`. As this is the same address as that of the array itself, we can (safely) cast this to an `mpz_t*` type in an assignment to `arg`:

```c
arg = (mpz_t*)temp;
```

But we can avoid a cast, here. One place where an array **does not decay** into a pointer is when it is the operand of the `&` (address of) operator (the other is when used as a `sizeof` operand). Thus, the expression, `&temp` will yield a type of `mpz_t*` that will be the address of the array:

```c
    if (flag) {
        mpz_mul_ui(temp, in, 2);
        arg = &temp; // RHS yields a `mpz_t*` type
    }
```

In the case of the other assignment (i.e., when the given `in` argument is the RHS), the situation is rather different and we *must* here use a cast. This is because that argument has *already* been converted to a pointer (its type is `__mpz_struct*`, as indicated in my suggested code, above). Also, any attempt to take its address will almost certainly yield an inappropriate/incorrect value – it will be the address of the passed argument (a pointer), likely on the stack.

So, as the *value* of the `in` argument is the address of the first element of the source array (used in the call to our function), we can cast that to an `mpz_t*` type and it can then be used as the address of that source array:

```c
    else {
        arg = (mpz_t*)in; // "in" has correct value but wrong type, so cast
    }
```

So, if you really want to use the `mpz_t*` type for your local `arg` variable, you can. But I would caution against using pointers to arrays wherever possible: they are prone to cause unexpected issues, later on, especially when you start using pointer arithmetic or indexing operations.

Comment: You could replace `__mpz_struct*` with `mpz_ptr`, which is equally as undocumented. :-)

Comment: @Ian Cool - I presume it is a GCC built-in type, otherwise the leading double underscore is seriously dodgy.

Comment: Not a built-in, just seriously dodgy.

Comment: @HugovanderSanden  I've added some further discussion to my answer and cleaned up the comments. Hope this clarifies the various issues for you.

Comment: Thanks, it all smacks a bit of "too much magic", but I intend to use this only in very simple ways.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't rant on about it in the answer, but it's actually a good example of why *not* to hide pointers and arrays behind `typedef` aliases. And the use of the leading double underscore is also poor design. But the authors of that package may have had their reasons.

Comment: @IanAbbott `mpz_ptr` is documented https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/doc/gmp.texi#l1991

Comment: @MarcGlisse That's an even better reason to use it! Since you added the documentation to the unstable development repo, do you know if there are any plans to add the documentation to the GMP 6.2 repo?

Comment: That's not really a priority. On the other hand, maybe there will be a 6.3 release in some not too distant future... (no promise)